# How to make images align well in html table?

Tags: html, css, web, tags

The issue is: book covers don't fit in the table cells. I want to make it look clean and neat.
[image: the issue]

I want to add best developer book covers on my blog. However, i have trouble to align them right. I use the **< td > ** tag for the first and second row of my table. Not **th**.

**I know the design is horrible.** 
Give me additional comments on how to improve the whole table. 
The images go out of borders in each cell.

---

Is there a special tool to make nicer tables?

Comment: if you want to see the original problem - it is on coding-solving blogspot com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a special tool to make nicer tables?

Yes, it's called CSS.

A sample CSS which would probably improve the appearence of your table would be:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 500px; /* 500px is an example */
}
table td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
table td img {
    max-width: 100px; /* divide 500 by the amount of books per row */
}
```

See it live at http://jsfiddle.net/46zUZ/6/

A good place to start learning CSS is http://htmldog.com/guides/css/

Comment: great, thanks for showing obvious things! but how about automatic tool to make it all align with one button?

Comment: You are asking for an automatic tool to do something very specific. The closest thing I can think of is by using Dreamweaver and doing some "select all" & "align to center", but still what I've described in that CSS is not possible as is via a tool.